# Working for conversion of odds to probability

Tags: probability

In this [course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bayesian-statistics), they show how to convert odds to probability showing the working from steps 1 to 3 below:

If an event B has a:b odds (with a > 0 and b > 0):

1. $P(B)/(1-P(B)) = a/b$
2. $P(B)*b = a-P(B)*a$
3. $P(B) = a/(a + b)$

I don't understand the algebraic logic how they got from 1 to 2 and then 2 to 3. What is the working between those steps? For step 2, I had $1 - P(B)*a$ on the right-hand side, not $a-P(B)*a$ and I can't see how to go from 2 to 3.

Comment: FYI, that page is locked behind a log-in screen.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{P(B)}{(1-P(B))} = \frac{a}{b}$$

$$P(B)\times b = a\times (1-P(B))$$

$$P(B)\times b = a-P(B)\times a$$

$$P(B)\times b + P(B)\times a = a$$

$$P(B)\times (a+b) = a$$

$$P(B) = \frac{a}{(a + b)}$$